# Converter node-csvtojson at sync mode do not returns json object

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to convert csv data to json with node-csvtojson.
Why doesn't [node-csvtojson](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson) return the converted to json string at async mode?

Code example from read.me:

```
const strindWithDelimiter='bla;bla;bla'
const csv=require('csvtojson')
// Async / await usage
const jsonArray=await csv().fromString(strindWithDelimiter);
console.log( jsonArray); <--- receive empty object wtihs node-csvtojson custom options
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been updated to latest version, and everything goes fine!
It was 1.1.9.